# Polynomial divisibility and automorphisms of cyclotomic fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

In my previous question [Maximal real subfields of Cyclotomic subfields giving rise to identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158350/maximal-real-subfields-of-cyclotomic-subfields-giving-rise-to-identities) I proved the following claim (I think):

**CLAIM**:If $\pi(x)$ is a monic irreducible polynomial such that $\pi(x)|\pi(x^2-2),$ then $\pi(x)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}$ over $\mathbb Q$, where $n$ is an odd natural number.

**Sketch of proof**:If $\pi(\alpha)=0,$ then $\pi(\alpha^2-2)=0,$ so $\tau:\alpha \rightarrow \alpha^2-2$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$.Construct the polynomial $x^2-\alpha.x+1$ with roots $\eta$  and $\eta^{-1}$.Extending $\tau$ to $\mathbb Q(\eta)$ and applying it to the quadratic, we will produce a quadratic with roots $\tau(\eta),\tau(\eta^{-1}),$ but a small calculation shows that they are also $\eta^2,\eta^{-2}$.So $\tau(\eta)=\eta^{\pm2},$ so  $\eta$ is a root of unity $\zeta_n$ and $n$ is odd.

Let $f_{n+1}(x)=x.f_{n}(x)-f_{n-1}(x)$ be a sequence of polynomials starting at 2 and x.Then $f_m(u+u^{-1})=u^m+u^{-m}$.Thus one can generalise the problem as follows:

**THEOREM**:If $\pi(x)$ is a monic irreducible polynomial such that $\pi(x)|\pi(f_m(x)),m>1,$ then $\pi(x)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}$ over $\mathbb Q$, where $(n,m)=1$.

All of this led me to consider $\pi(x)|\pi(g(x)),$ for an arbitrary $g(x)$.This is equivalent to asking for which $\alpha$ is $\tau:\alpha \rightarrow g(\alpha)$ an automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\alpha),$ since $\pi(x)$ is defined by $\alpha,$ being its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb Q$.

**QUESTION 1**: What really is going on that allows us to construct an auxiliary polynomial that works so well in the case of the theorem?Is there a more illuminating proof of the claim?My proof feels very contrived and unnatural.

**QUESTION 2**:Are these methods applicable to the general case?

Here are some of my thoughts: the case when $g(x)=x^2-2$ corresponds to $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1})=\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)^H$,$H={(\pm1)}=G^{\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}}$,which is normal over Q, so all conjugates are expressible as "polynomials". What g is is simply one such polynomial.Expressing $\alpha=\eta+\eta^{-1}$ just allows us to apply g to it and arrive at $\eta^2+\eta^{-2},$ a conjugate.But constructing the auxiliary polynomial is crucial for the proof.When I tried to apply analogous reasoning for $H=G^{\frac{\varphi(n)}{3}}={(1,s,s^2)}<Z_n^*$ I couldn't construct a nice polynomial.What I think we should do here is this:$\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)^H=\mathbb Q(\zeta_n+\zeta_n^s+\zeta_n^{s^2}),$ so g here is a polynomial sending $\zeta_n+\zeta_n^s+\zeta_n^{s^2}$ to a conjugate.I think we should construct a polynomial whose roots mimick the behaviour of $\zeta_n,\zeta_n^s,\zeta_n^{s^2},$ and then apply g to it, but I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: recommend this 1875 book, I bought a paperback reprint; it has, at least, many relevant examples:  https://books.google.com/books?id=wt7lgfeYqMQC&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&source=bl&ots=VGZFPrfUBn&sig=MlQ667PqXaQ9rAvLWkG3_F1rwsk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwtSvm9TQAhUJ-2MKHXJIA_kQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false

Comment: Looked at your previous question, you should definitely take a look at the Reuschle book, if only on line. Your $x^3 + x^2 - 2 x - 1$ is on page 6. The method for construction is due to Gauss. I learned of it in David A. Cox, ***Galois Theory.***

Comment: Am I missing something or is the THEOREM fals for $m=1$?

Comment: @WillJagy  So this is basically a giant table of subfields of cyclotomic fields and the algebraic relations in them?That's cool, but I am not as interested in finding the $g(x)$ (as in the question), but in finding an analogue to $x^2-\alpha.x+1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen oh yeah, it doesn't work because then the "automorphism" sends $\eta$ to itself, so we cannot conclude that it is a root of unity.Thanks for mentioning

Comment: In your theorem do we have to understand that $f_2(x) = x^2-2$, and $f_3(x) = x^3-3x$  etc? Now does the statement supposes the equality is valid $forall m$ or just for one of the $m$?  In question 5 what do you mean  by general case? an "auxillary polynomial" of higher degree? and what is the reccursive difinition then?

Comment: @MarcBogaerts yes, that is the sequence.Also it is valid for all coprime m and n.The general case is when the f_i are replaced by an arbitrary polynomial.Then we dont have to have a recursion.The recursion is there just to define the polynomials for which my auxiliary quadratic works, i.e. the ones that obey $f(u+u^{-1})=u^k+u^{-k}$.Take a look at my previous post if you haven't already, which only deals with f_2

Comment: Ok, but it's still not clear tbat tbe polynomial $g$ has to be quadratic or not.

Comment: @MarcBogaerts no it doesn't , it can be anything, like x^3-3x, as you mentioned, or just anything at all.My proof works in the sequence f_i because of the algebraic identity and the auxiliary $x^2-\alpha.x+1$

Comment: So maybe it's  interesting to know that in $\Bbb F_{13}$ the conjugates of $\zeta_{13}+\zeta_{13}^3+\zeta_{13}^9$ the polynomial $2/3x^3+x^2+4/3x-2$ is such a polynomial.

Comment: @MarcBogaerts weirdly enough, I worked that same example out just as you commented!Do you have any idea how we solve the problem for this polynomial, for instance?

Comment: It's a bit too extensive for a comment, but the example can be generalized to other subfields (I think)

Comment: @MarcBogaerts can you give me at least a little bit of a hint as to how we can do that?

Comment: @MarcBogaerts if you have a proof,I guess it would work only for subfields of cyclotomic fields?And does your proof use the same idea as the one in the question?

Comment: Indeed. I simply substitute the values of the polynomial and solve for the coefficients (linear equations).

Comment: Im sorry if this is obvious, but I dont really understand how that works.

Comment: @MarcBogaerts excuse me if Im asking too much, but can you give a small example in an answer perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

As an example in $\Bbb F_{13}$ with Galois group $G = C_{12}$, we chose a group with index $4$, so H = $\langle g^4 \rangle$ where $g$ is a generator of $G$. To find the invariant field corresponding to H I take the orbit of $\zeta$ under $H$ and take its sum giving $\eta = \zeta + \zeta^3 + \zeta^9$. The orbit of $\eta$ is $\{\eta, \zeta^2 + \zeta^5 + \zeta^6, \zeta^4 + \zeta^{10} + \zeta^{12}, \zeta^{7} + \zeta^8 + \zeta^{11}\}$, which I take as a basis of the subfield fixed by $H$ then I take the matrix $M$ whose rows are formed by the coefficients of the elements $1, \eta, \eta^2, \eta^3$ giving :
$$ M = 
\begin{pmatrix}  
-1 & -1 & -1& -1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
-5 & -3 & -6 & -3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
To find out which combination of these rows gives the second (for example) element of the orbit I solve (I like column vectors, that's why the transpose) 
$$ 
(M^t)^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}  
0\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}  
-2\\
4/3\\
1\\
2/3
\end{pmatrix}
\implies 
\begin{pmatrix}  
1 & x & x^2 & x^3\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}  
-2\\
4/3\\
1\\
2/3
\end{pmatrix}
 = 2/3x^3+x^2+4/3x-2
$$ 
HTH